# Is there a Linear Transformer which uses only Matrix operations?

Tags: algorithm-analysis

I am interested in finding a Linear Transformer which only uses **ONLY** matrix operations (more specifically matrix-matrix multiplications during training and matrix-vector multiplication in inference time).

The linear transformer should avoid elementwise operations like the GeLU (Gaussian error Linear Unit) in SLiM ([Sub-Linear Memory How to Make Performers SLiM](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.11346)), look the image below (taken from section 2.2):

[image]

The best I could find on google is H-Transformer-1D ([H-Transformer-1D: Fast One-Dimensional Hierarchical Attention for Sequences](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.11906.pdf)) but I don't understand well it because it uses Multigrid methods (a numerical method for solving large-scale sparse
matrices resulting from discretized partialdifferential equations (PDEs)).

Question: Does H-Transformer-1D uses **ONLY** matrix operations? Is there other transformer using only matrix operations?

Comment: Attention itself is not linear really since it uses softmax which involves both element-wise operations and a reduction (and in practice also involves a max reduction).

Also if all you had was matmuls the result would be linear. It might be more efficient if your attention analog was O(n^2) rather than the O(n^3) of one giant matmul. It would however still not learn interesting things since it would just be a sparse matmul.

Maybe we could help more if you explained *why* you wanted to only use matmuls.

Comment: I am interested in knowing how many times GPU implementations of dense matrix multiplications (like [DBCSR: A Library for Dense Matrix Multiplications on Distributed GPU-Accelerated Systems](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.04796.pdf)) will accelerate transformer training/inference...

Comment: I have never stated Attention is linear... and I think (I say "I think" because I am not a researcher or authority in the area) when someone says "linear", he is implicitly talking about a method to avoid storing/computing matrix-matrix multiplication like for example approximating a matrix-matrix multiplication by low rank matrices...

Comment: Do you mean you want a linear *time* transformer like LinFormer or BigBird? BigBird literally just reduces the number of pair-wise comparisons for attention in a static way so that might be what you're looking for? Also why do you care about element-wise operations? It seems nearly impossible to implement any network without element-wise operations?

Also if you want to do a comparison why not just run such a transformer both with and without this network? I assure you that the matmuls will entirely dominate the compute costs even in the case of networks like BigBird.

Comment: "Do you mean you want a linear time transformer like LinFormer or BigBird?" yes, I am talking about time.

Comment: BigBird is not a solution because is still has a scoring function sigma (e.g. softmax or hardmax) (section 2 - [Big Bird: Transformers for Longer Sequences](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.14062.pdf)): $\operatorname{ATTN}_{D}(\boldsymbol{X})_{i}=\boldsymbol{x}_{i}+\sum_{h=1}^{H} \sigma\left(Q_{h}\left(\boldsymbol{x}_{i}\right) K_{h}\left(\boldsymbol{X}_{N(i)}\right)^{T}\right) \cdot V_{h}\left(\boldsymbol{X}_{N(i)}\right)$

Comment: Your question: "why not just run such a transformer both with and without this network?". My answer: When I started studied the most basic form of a neural network, I have read the generalization hability of a neural network is deeply related to the nonliearity of the activation function (sigmoid function for the most basic neural and other more modern activation functions like GeLU for modern transformers for example). If I run SLiM without GeLU I will not be able to assess the generalization hability of the transformer, so I don't dare to make such a huge modification...

Comment: and I will not be able to assess the generalization hability of the transformer because I am not a researcher able to do that...